# IsInSharepoint field is false for some FBA user in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

We have noticed in our SharePoint website that sometimes if the new user registered then some fields are not properly updated in FBA user management list. Below are the fields which are not updated as expected for some users:

```
IsInSharePoint : No    (it should be Yes)
FullName : empty    (it should contain the user name)
Modified: empty     (it should be the modified date)
Created: empty     (it should be the created date)
```

Note: Screenshot is attached. [image]

Can anyone please help why it is occurring?

Comment: we are also facing the same issue. can any expert help us on this. [![**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSYcl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSYcl.png)